# C++ 2D arrays with different number of columns

Tags: arrays, dynamic, 2d

I would like to build a 2D dynamic array that - when populated - should look like the following:

```
xxx
xxxxx
xx
x
xxxxxxx
```

That is, each row will have a number of columns that I cannot know in advance. I have tried to define this in the following way:

```
int nRows = 10;
int **X = new int *[nRows];
for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++)
 {
   int nCols = rand()%10;
   X[i] = new int[nCols];
 }
```

Do you find anything wrong with this representation?

Thanks a lot for your time,
Ripo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: `nCols` might be 0, so you should do `nCols = 1+rand()%10` instead.

In addition, how are you planning to know the size of each row after you've allocated it?

You will need to save a separate array containing the size of each row, or add a "dummy" entry at the end of each row in order to mark the end of that row.

Here is how you can maintain an additional array containing the size of each row:

```
int nRows = 10;
int **X = new int *[nRows];
int *S  = new int  [nRows];

for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++)
{
    int nCols = 1+rand()%10;
    X[i] = new int[nCols];
    S[i] = nCols;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. In fact in my code I have taken care of the "0" size in the columns and the size of the columns for each row, although in this example I have obviously not. So, for sake of clarity lets follow  your code as template. Is it ok to follow this representation? Because for some reason, later on, it crashes, and I trying to find the problem by elimination. Thank you again!

Comment: I cannot say it's a good template, because I'm not sure about your general intentions with this code. If it crashes elsewhere, then you should post a different question with all the relevant information.